# Resize silverlight control as per browser window size

Tags: c#, silverlight, crm

I have silverlight web resource on my entity form. I need to resize it as per the window size.

my requirement is if I open page in full size it should display in normal size while I have set as default in User Control tag.

but , if i restore down , than horizontal scroll should display.

I have data grid in my silverlight control , columns width should be fix.

I have tried below,  but fails.

```
 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

Comment: If it's not invoking your ScrollViewer it's usually to do with the layout setting the potential boundary for it to be invoked, like if you have it in a Grid cell set to Auto or just in a StackPanel as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I find the ScrollViewer used through the Attached Property doesn't always respond as it should in Silverlight.

Try using the ScrollViewer control and wrap the DataGrid, but only set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility. Set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to disabled to let the DataGrids built in ScrollViewer to work.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
   <DataGrid>
      ...
   </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```